Scrolling to the end of a multiline textbox in vb.net Web
I have a web form in vb.net and a multiline textbox.  I need to add predefined text (selected by the user) and append it to the textbox.  However, the user requires that every time the text is appended, the text box automatically scrolls to the end to show the new appended text.  I have tried multiple options, including .ScrollToCaret() and .SelStart(), but those methods are not available in a Web form.  Also, .Append() method does not do it.  This is a Web Application under vb.net in Visual Studio 2022.  Any help would be appreciated.
I try this, but it is not supported:
    With txtIndicacionesExtras
        .Text &= Texto
        .SelStart = &HFFFF&       'Len(TextBox.Text) is less efficient than a constant value
        .SelText = "Text to append"
        .SelText = vbNewLine
        txtIndicacionesExtras. = .Text.Length
        .ScrollToCaret()
    End With


This question is similar to: Use JavaScript to place cursor at end of text in text input element. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
